# Accepted status-answered boxes are not clearly visible

Tags: support, feature-request, design

Here is how to looks on my serverfault profile (`/users/%/%?tab=questions&sort=newest`):

[image: serverfault status-answered boxes]

The problem is, that answered questions are not clearly visible between those which are accepted and which are not.

In other words I'm really having problem finding which answer is accepted and which is not.

Secondly it seems that the darker color (which looks like black) means the question has accepted answer, the light green means it doesn't. Shouldn't be this opposite?

In comparison this is how it looks on stackoverflow:

[image: stackoverflow status-answered boxes]

Can this be improved on this site?

Comment: I actually have quite a few problems with readability when trying to read the site on my work laptops. But this one is probably the most blatant one. +1